# How do I join with multiple SQL tables and return one row per base table record with the correct GROUP_CONCAT data?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-concat

I have a situation where I want to join multiple SQL tables and get back one row per record in the base table as well as `GROUP_CONCAT` the other table data together with `|`. Unfortunately, with the query method I'm currently using, I'm getting back undesired multiplicity in the `GROUP_CONCAT` data and I don't know how to solve it.

I have the following basic DB structure:

```
things
id | name
1  | Some Thing
2  | Some Other Thing

items
id | name
1  | Blob
2  | Starfish
3  | Wrench
4  | Stereo

users
id | name
1  | Alice
2  | Bill
3  | Charlie
4  | Daisy

things_items
thing_id | item_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 3
2        | 4

things_users
thing_id | user_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
1        | 3
2        | 4
```

And I would ideally like to write a query that gets back the following for the `Some Thing` row in the `things` table:

```
Some Thing | Blob|Starfish | Alice|Bill|Charlie
```

However, what I'm getting back is the following:

```
Some Thing | Blob|Blob|Blob|Starfish|Starfish|Starfish | Alice|Alice|Bill|Bill|Charlie|Charlie
```

And this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT things.name,
        GROUP_CONCAT(items.name SEPARATOR '|')
        GROUP_CONCAT(users.name SEPARATOR '|')
FROM things
    JOIN things_items ON things.id = things_items.thing_id
    JOIN items ON things_items.item_id = items.id
    JOIN things_users ON things.id = things_users.thing_id
    JOIN users ON things_items.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY things.id;
```

How should I change the query to get the data back the way I'd like to and avoid the multiplying of the `GROUP_CONCAT` data? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try DISTINCT: `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT items.name SEPARATOR '|')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating along two separate dimensions.  The simplest solution is `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT t.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.name SEPARATOR '|')
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.name SEPARATOR '|')
FROM things t JOIN
     things_items ti
     ON t.id = ti.thing_id JOIN
     items i
     ON ti.item_id = i.id JOIN
     things_users tu
     ON t.id = tu.thing_id JOIN
     users u
     ON tu.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY t.id;
```

Note the above filters out things that have either no items or no users.

The above will work fine if there are a handful of items and users for each thing.  As the numbers grow, the performance gets worse because it generates a Cartesian product for each thing.

That can be solved by aggregating before joining:

```
SELECT t.name, i.items, u.users
FROM things t JOIN
     (SELECT ti.thing_id, GROUP_CONCAT(i.name SEPARATOR '|') as items
      FROM things_items ti JOIN
           items i
           ON ti.item_id = i.id
      GROUP BY ti.thing_id
     ) i
     ON t.id = ti.thing_id JOIN         
     (SELECT tu.user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT u.name SEPARATOR '|') as users
      FROM things_users tu JOIN
           users u
           ON tu.user_id = u.id
      GROUP BY tu.user_id
     ) tu
      ON t.id = tu.thing_id ;
```

You can replace the outer `JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN` if you want all things, even those with no items or names.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, this is a phenomenal answer and it solves my problem perfectly. Thank you so much!